An estimate involving Poisson Kernel
Let $I$ be the open interval $(x_0,x_0+h)$ and $f=4\chi_I$. How can I show that
$$u(x,y)=(P_y*f)(x)>1$$
for all $(x,y)\in I\times (0,h)$, where $P_y$ is the Poisson kernel of the upper half plane and $*$ denotes the convolution. I want to know this estimate because it is used in the proof of a characterization of Carleson measure (Reference: page 31 of GTM236, Bounded Analytic Functions).

We have $$ u(x,y)={4y\over \pi}\int\limits_{x_0-x}^{x_0-x+h}{1\over t^2+y^2}\,dt \\ ={4\over \pi}\int\limits_{(x_0-x)/y}^{(x_0-x+h)/y}{1\over t^2+1}\,dt  $$ The interval of integration contains $0$ and its length is equal $h/y.$ The integrated function is even and decreasing on the positive half axis. Therefore the smallest value of the integral  is attained for the interval $[0,h/y].$ Hence we get the lower estimate $$u(x,y)\ge {4\over \pi}\int\limits_{0}^{h/y}{1\over t^2+1}\,dt=  {4\over \pi} \arctan(h/y)\ge {4\over \pi} {\pi\over 4}=1$$

Thanks for your answer! May you explain more about the first inequality? Since $x_0-x<0$, we don't have $(x_0-x+h,x_0-x)\supset (h,0)$, so I don't really see why the first inequality holds.

I have extended the answer explaining the inequality.
